# “They are…” vs. “these are...” when answering the question" Whose xxx are these?

Tags: grammar, whose

When people ask me:

> "Whose xx are these"?

Which one should I use to answer them:

> 1. "They are...."
> 2. "These are..."？

Which one is grammatically correct?

Comment: Which one do you think is grammatical? Is there a reason why you think one of them might not be grammatical?

Comment: I think"These are.." may be right，because it matches the question，but  I'm not sure，I saw some people used"They are" ,so I'm confused ..

Comment: I recommend "They are mine" or "They're mine"  rather than "These [or "Those] are mine."  Both are grammatical, however.

Comment: So they are both right!!Thank you so much!! but if I my answer is "... are my XXX"，"They are my Xxx" and "These are my XXX" are both right?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there are two common ways of answering the question:

> **They** are mine.
>   **Those** are mine.

While you can hold up some items and declare, ***These*** *are mine!*, the response to **these** would normally *not* be **these** in return.

(Conversely, if somebody asks *Whose are* ***those***?, while pointing at something you are holding, the response likely *would* be ***These*** *are mine.*)

The use of *these* typically implies objects that are close to a speaker, while *those* implies objects that are farther away.

[**This**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/this) (plural, *these*):

> a (1) : the person, thing, or idea that is present or near in place,
>   time, or thought or that has just been mentioned · *these* are my hands

[**That**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/that) (plural, *those*):

> a : the person, thing, or idea indicated, mentioned, or understood
>   from the situation · *that* is my father

However, **they** can be used in response to either form of question. But I'd argue it's a  less common response than using the "complement" of the word used to ask the question . . .

---

Note: There is a particular circumstance I can think of when **these** could be used in answer to **these**:

> "Oh, look," she said, spreading her arms as they walked through the storage room door. "Whose are all of these?"
>   "*These*," he replied, "are mine."

In this usage, the objects being referenced are separate from both speakers.

(The equivalent usage could apply to two people standing next to each other, where one points off into the distance and **those** is used in both question and answer.)